# can we disabled keyboard input on electron js

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I want to disabled keyboard input on Electronjs `webview`. only allowed the mouse to operational.

here is my code that is responsible for render `webview`.

```html
<div class="page">
   <div class="main">
      <webview
         id="webview"
         class="webview" 
         style="display: inline-flex;"
         src="https://github.com">
      </webview>
      <webview id="captureWebview" src="about:blank">
      </webview>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for but if you are disabling shortcut you should refer to https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts

For example if you want to disable everything you can probably do

```
if (webviewIsOpenOrLoaded) { // you may want to have a tracking variable and set it to true when your webview is open
    window.addEventListener('keyup', () => null, true)
}
```

Though I'm not sure whether this is a good thing to do or not.